# What are all the “special filenames” recognized by Cargo?

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-cargo

Cargo has a number of special filenames that it recognizes during the build process. For example, build.rs provides build instructions, lib.rs/main.rs are entry points, and mod.rs is a module. I’d like to avoid accidentally naming my modules something that might be treated specially, or that might be misinterpreted as being treated specially.

Is there a complete listing of all the “special” filenames that Cargo recognizes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [good overview](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) in the cargo book.

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/
│   ├── lib.rs
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── bin/
│       ├── named-executable.rs
│       ├── another-executable.rs
│       └── multi-file-executable/
│           ├── main.rs
│           └── some_module.rs
├── benches/
│   ├── large-input.rs
│   └── multi-file-bench/
│       ├── main.rs
│       └── bench_module.rs
├── examples/
│   ├── simple.rs
│   └── multi-file-example/
│       ├── main.rs
│       └── ex_module.rs
└── tests/
    ├── some-integration-tests.rs
    └── multi-file-test/
        ├── main.rs
        └── test_module.rs
```

But all of those are just defaults and you can change them via settings in the `Cargo.toml` file.
`build.rs` shouldn't ever clash with modules since it lives in the root rather than under `src/`

I don't think `mod.rs` is cargo specific but rather how rust modules are defined.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't mind learning about magic filenames for the Rust compiler too, if "mod.rs" counts as such. Very helpful to learn about the benches/ and examples/ special directories though!